# Boucle multido error while compiling to transform qcm A4pages into A5

Tags: compiling, multido

Could somebody help me to find where the error is with "Missing number, treated as zero " in the code below please???

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
    \usepackage{multido}

    % m page's number for each student (ici 7 pages by student)
    % n total number of student
    % p = n*m total number for all student equal to n*m

           \newcounter{m} 
            \setcounter{m}{7} 
            \newcounter{n}
            \setcounter{n}{5}   
            \begin{document}  
            \multido{\i=0+1}{n}{  
  \includepdf[pages={1-(m-2)},nup=1x2,landscape,signature=36]{DOC-sujet.pdf}
  \includepdf[pages={(m-1)-m},nup=1x2,landscape,signature=4]{DOC-sujet.pdf}

         \addtocounter{m}{7} 
              } 
             \end{document}
```

Comment: I think someone has to flag the question for help of an italic speaker (But I don't really know if we have to flag or just wait for someone to edit). https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/693/120578. @Kofi if you can speak some English please edit your question yourself

Comment: @koleygr Why do you think than all Italian speakers know French?

Comment: Crosspost http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=30731

Comment: Sorry that you don't speak french. I have add in the end that I am need help to compile my file in latex. When doing it I have got an error "missing number, treated as zero .Could somebody help me to find where the error is with "Missing number, treated as zero " in the code below please???

Comment: [Another Crosspost](http://texnique.fr/osqa/questions/4919/boucle-iterative-multido-et-erreur-de-compilation-latex-qcm)

Answer (score 3):

Use `multido` for all counters:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} \usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{multido}   % m nombre de page par étudiant(ici 7 pages par étudiant) 
% n nombre total d'étudiant 
% p = n*m  nombre total de page du document 
% m=7   

\begin{document}  
\multido{\iM=7+7,\im=5+7,\iN=6+7}{5}{%  
  \includepdf[pages={1-\im},
     nup=1x2,landscape,signature=36]{DOC-sujet.pdf}
  \includepdf[pages={\iN-\iM},
     nup=1x2,landscape,signature=4]{DOC-sujet.pdf}
} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I understund why you have chang m into iM and n into iN and so on?

Comment: `i` is for integer, that's all. Easier to remember

Comment: With my code here are the error I ve got: Missing number, treated as zero }

Comment: Your example or my example?

Comment: With mine! With your' s I have many error that I can't handle...because I don't understand very well what you are doing..

Comment: After making change according to your's I have got the same error! Missing number treated as zero.

Comment: Did _my_ example as it is (without any change)  run without a problem?

Comment: Here is the error abut your code: Package pdftex.def Error: File `\AM@currentdocname .png' not found }.      Can you explain to me what is your code is suppose to do ?

Comment: It looks like that you wrote `DOC-sujet.png`  instead of `...pdf`??

Comment: No it doc.pdf! I have think it is taking Im or iM as png image files...

Comment: then provide your complete code!

Comment: Sorry, this was all the code I have write...nor less nor more...

Comment: When running _my_ example, did you had the file `DOC-sujet.pdf` in the same directory?

Comment: ok, I have got no error now but let understand your code! I would like to understand it. Mine is attended to transform the m A4 pages for each student to 2A5 page for a total of n student. So doc-sujet.pdf is a total of m*n pages. Each last 2 pages of each student should be keept in A4 format. That is my goal.